# How do I recalculate normals for all objects in the scene?

Tags: normals

How do I recalculate normals for all objects in the scene? Normally, I select an object at a time, press Tab, press a to select all vertices/faces and press Ctrl-n. If I have 20+ objects in the scene, can do it in one hit combo?

Comment: No. You'll have to use python.

Comment: Here is a quick [script](http://bpaste.net/show/180650/) to do this.